# I am making a stock prediction project for educational purposes

Tags: python-3.x, lstm

I entered a code for my project in which I was using an LSTM model and when I was retrieving data from yahoo this error occured

```
#load Data
company = 'AAPL'
start = dt.datetime(2021,12,17)
end = dt.datetime(2022,12,17)
data = web.DataReader(company,'yahoo',start,end)
print(data)
```

This was my code and as per the video I was working on it, this should've printed stock values for the past year of apple
Instead:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-282e8a3c419c> in <module>
      3 start = dt.datetime(2021,12,17)
      4 end = dt.datetime(2022,12,17)
----> 5 data = web.DataReader(company,'yahoo',start,end)
      6 print(data)
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers
This was the output

Answer (score 0):

You are providing an `int` to a `datetime.datetime()` object here:

```
start = dt.datetime(2021,12,17)
end = dt.datetime(2022,12,17)
```

This results in a type of `datetime.datetime`. Be sure to cast this type to an `int` as this is what the `DataReader` method is expecting:

```
start = int(dt.datetime(2021,12,17))
end = int(dt.datetime(2022,12,17))
```